# Creating a library project in Android Studio + saving in a git repository + using as a dependency

Tags: android, git, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I read a lot of tutorials about how to create an android library project, but non of them walked me through the entire flow of "Creating the lib" -> "Saving in a git repo" -> "Using as a dependency"

For **Creating the lib**, I can either follow [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/daniellevass/2c46cf33e3814e685b47) (*Option A*) or create a project and simply create a new module (*Option B*). I prefer *Option B*, because it enables me to create an example application that uses the lib.

- **Saving in a git repo:**

  1. Which folder should I push into the git repo? The Project's root folder, or the module's? What are the pros/cons?
- **Using as a dependency:** I can either use this library as a git submodule, or a maven dependency.

  1. Which of the 2 would you recommend for an in-house library? Why?
  2. Say I chose *Option B* for the project structure, how will it be possible for the projects that are not using my library to NOT have the example application?

Comment: Did you find any answer?